# R - Removing the same name in two columns of a data frame

Tags: r

I am working with a data frame that has two columns, name and spouse. I am trying to calculate the interracial marriage frequency, but I need to remove repeated registers. 
When I have the name of a creature I need to keep this register in the data frame but remove the register where that creature name is the spouse name. I have this following data sample:

```
                    name                      spouse
15                  Finarfin                  EÃ¤rwen
6             Tar-VanimeldÃ«                  Herucalmo
17                   Faramir                  owyn
8               Tar-Meneldur                  Almarian
14   Finduilas of Dol Amroth                  Denethor II
12                    FinwÃ«                  MÃ­riel SerindÃ« then ,Indis
9              Tar-AncalimÃ«                  Hallacar
7                Tar-MÃ­riel                   Ar-PharazÃ´n
5          Tarannon Falastur                  BerÃºthiel
21             Rufus Burrows                  Asphodel Brandybuck
2                     Angrod                  EldalÃ³tÃ«
4               Ar-GimilzÃ´r                  InzilbÃªth
19 Lobelia Sackville-Baggins                  Otho Sackville-Baggins
25            Mrs. Proudfoot                  Odo Proudfoot
22            Rudigar Bolger                  Belba Baggins
24             Odo Proudfoot                  Mrs. Proudfoot
3               Ar-PharazÃ´n                  Tar-MÃ­riel
13                 Fingolfin                  AnairÃ«
18                SilmariÃ«n                  Elatan
23           Rowan Greenhand                  Belba Baggins
20                     RÃ­an                   Huor
1                     Adanel                  Belemir
16           Fastolph Bolger                  Pansy Baggins
10         Morwen Steelsheen                  Thengel
11              Tar-Aldarion                  Erendis
25              Belemir                       Adanel
```

For example, I ran the code and in line 1 it caught name Adanel and got Belemir as its spouse, so I need to keep line 1, but remove line 25, because with that I will avoid duplicated data.

I have tried this following code:

```
interacialMariage <-data %>% filter(spouse != name) %>% select(name, spouse)
```

How can I get the same spouse name register out of the data frame registers?

P.S.: I would need it to avoid case sensitive (Belemir == belemir) so that I don't have problems in the future.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up another vector with the row-wise alphabetically sorted names, and deduplicate using that...

```
sorted <- sapply(1:nrow(data), 
                 function(i) paste(sort(c(trimws(tolower(data$name[i])),
                                        trimws(tolower(data$spouse[i])))),
                                   collapse=" ")) 
irM <- data[!duplicated(sorted),]
```

The `trimws` strips off any leading or trailing spaces before sorting and pasting, and `tolower` converts everything to lower case.

Comment: It didn't work. It shows me this error:                                                                 
`Error in sort(trimws(tolower(interacialMariage$name[i])), trimws(tolower(interacialMariage$spouse[i]))) : 
  'decreasing' must be a logic vector of length 1`

Comment: @Codewraith Sorry about that - I've edited the answer to solve that problem.

Comment: I don't have the error anymore, but it didn't solve my problem, I still have 2 registers that have Belemir on it, one as name and other as a spouse. The irM has the same size of data, so I think it didn't remove the duplicated. Do you know why?

Comment: @Codewraith Sorry - try again with the amended version above - I think it needs a `collapse` argument

Answer (score 1):

My attempt with `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  mutate(id = 1:n()) %>%           # add id to label the pairs
  gather('key', 'name', -id) %>%   # transform: key (name | spouse), name, id
  group_by(name) %>%               # group by unique name to find duplicated
  top_n(-1, wt = id) %>%           # if name > 1, take row with the lower id
  spread(key, name) %>%            # spread data to original format
  select(-id)                      # remove id's

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   name              spouse       
#   <chr>             <chr>        
# 1 Adanel            Belemir      
# 2 Fastolph Bolger   Pansy Baggins
# 3 Morwen Steelsheen Thengel
```

Data:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  name   = c("Adanel",  "Fastolph Bolger", "Morwen Steelsheen", "Belemir"),
  spouse = c("Belemir", "Pansy Baggins",   "Thengel",           "Adanel" ),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)
```

Comment: I have tried this code : `interacialMariage %>% + your code`.
It showed this error: `Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables;
they will be dropped  `

Comment: It is not an error, but warning. Convert `name` and `spouse` to character type and you'll not see it again.

Comment: Now this error is happening: `Error: n() should only be called in a data context`           
I have just changed `dat` (from your code) to `interacialMariage` (that is my data frame). Do you know why this error is happening?